# how to filter formview using 2 textbox for date range, and the button, then another textbox and its button from code behind,

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
protected void btnsc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string startdate = datesearch.Text.ToString();
        string enddate = todates.Text.ToString();
        string fe = "";
        if (startdate != "" && enddate != "" )
        {
            fe = "RenDate >= '" + startdate + "' and RenDate <= '" + enddate+ "'";
        }
        else if (startdate != "" && enddate == "" )
        {
            fe = "RenDate >= '" + startdate+"'";
        }
        else if (startdate == "" && enddate != "" )
        {
            fe = "RenDate <= '" + enddate + "'";
        }
         markdatas.FilterExpression = fe;
        //rebind GridView1
        markdatas.DataBind();
    }
```

The above code works fine, however the bellow code is not working, its another button that shoulde filter using different field in the formview,

```
 protected void strSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string paramm = txtFind.Text.ToString();
        string fe = "";
        if (paramm != "")
        {
            fe = "Mark  ='" + paramm + "' ";
        }

        markdatas.FilterExpression = fe;
        markdatas.DataBind();
    }
```

Comment: Your help is greatly appreaciated

Comment: Have you debug your code? what its return?

Comment: `Textbox` always returns a string value see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox.text?view=netframework-4.5) therefore no need to use `ToString()`. If possible kindly share your data access layer logic.

Comment: @Suprabhat Biswal, i am a beginner i dont understand what you really want me to share, do you mean the connection to my dataBase?, if so i am using the access database SQlDatasource, so markdatas is the Formview ID

Comment: @Cool JK, i tried debugging its not returning anything.

Comment: <asp:SqlDataSource ID="markdatas" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString17 %>" ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString17.ProviderName %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Agent], [AgentRef], [Correspondent], [Proprietor], [Country], [Mark], [TMNumber], [TMCountry], [RenDate],[To Lapse?] AS column1, [Archived?] AS column2, [TMS], [TMS2], [AddrServ], [logo], [key] FROM [Mark]" FilterExpression="">

Comment: Should the second button combine with the filter from the first, or do you want the filters completely separate, like they are now?

Answer (score 0):

The problem looks like you have a duplicate name, which could cause a conflict.  You are using a table named `[Mark]` and a field named `[Mark]`.  You need to alias one of them.  I would recommend aliasing the table, so you don't need to change any of your code.

Change your query to this:

```
SELECT [Agent], [AgentRef], [Correspondent], [Proprietor], 
    [Country], [Mark], [TMNumber], [TMCountry], [RenDate],
    [To Lapse?] AS column1, [Archived?] AS column2, [TMS], 
    [TMS2], [AddrServ], [logo], [key] 
    FROM [Mark] AS MarkTable
```